# Lambda conversions with unclear return type and overload resolution

Tags: c#, lambda, overload-resolution

If I have a lambda such as `() => { throw new Exception(); }`, it's unclear whether it has a return type or not. Because of this, it can be (implicitly) converted to both `Action` and `Func<object>` (or any other `Func<T>`). This is because, according to §6.5 *Anonymous function conversions* of the C# 4 spec:

> [A] delegate type `D` is compatible with an anonymous function `F` provided:
>
> - …
> - If `D` has a `void` return type and the body of `F` is a statement block, when […] the body of `F` is a valid statement block in which no return statement specifies an expression.
> - If `D` has a non-void return type and the body of `F` is a statement block, when […] the body of `F` is a valid statement block with a non-reachable end point in which each `return` statement specifies an expression that is implicitly convertible to the return type of `D`.

But if I have two overloads of a method, where one has a parameter of type `Action` and the other `Func<object>`, and I pass it the lambda from above, the `Func<object>` overload is used. Why? Which part of specification says that `Func<object>` is better than `Action` in this case?

I have looked at §7.5.3.2 *Better function member*, but that does not explain it.

Comment: And if, instead of lambda syntax, you use the notation `delegate { throw new Exception(); }` where you leave out the parameter list in `()` parentheses, that anonymous function could match **any** delegate signature I guess, including also e.g. `EventHandler` and `Action<object, EventArgs>`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yeah. In that case, there really is no rule to disambiguate them as method parameters, so you would get a compile error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I should've looked one section lower: §7.5.3.3 *Better conversion from expression* explains that:

> Given an implicit conversion `C1` that converts from an expression `E` to a type `T1`, and an implicit conversion `C2` that converts from an expression `E` to a type `T2`, `C1` is a better conversion than `C2` if at least one of the following holds:
>
> - …
> - `E` is an anonymous function, `T1` is either a delegate type `D1` or an expression tree type `Expression<D1>`, `T2` is either a delegate type `D2` or an expression tree type `Expression<D2>` and one of the following holds:
>
>   - …
>   - `D1` and `D2` have identical parameter lists, and one of the following holds:
>
>     - …
>     - **`D1` has a return type `Y`, and `D2` is void returning**

Comment: You've posted this answer in the same second as you've asked the question?

Comment: Yeah, while I was writing the question, I noticed the answer in the spec. So I didn't want to waste anyone's time researching this. But at the same time, I thought it could be useful for someone else.

Comment: This answer explains how the observed behavior fits the spec, but it doesn't (and can't) explain why the spec was written that way in the first place. Luckily, [we now have word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316189/peculiar-overload-resolution-with-while-true/24316474?noredirect=1#comment37681268_24316474) from the person who implemented the feature in the compiler explaining that as well!