# Why throwing OperationCanceledException gets me different results?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

My co-worker played with TPL and task cancellations. He showed me the following code:

```
var cancellationToken = cts.Token;
var task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(300);
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            throw new OperationCanceledException();
        }
    }

}, cancellationToken)
    .ContinueWith(t => {
        Console.WriteLine(t.Status);
    });

Thread.Sleep(200);
cts.Cancel();
```

This prints "Canceled" as expected, but if you just comment **while** line like this:

```
// ..
//while (true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(300);
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        throw new OperationCanceledException();
    }
}
//..
```

you'll get "Faulted". I am well aware about **ThrowIfCancellationRequested()** method and that I should pass **cancellationToken** in the constructor of OperationCanceledException (and this leads to "Canceled" result in both cases) but anyway I can't explain why this happens.

Comment: You haven't cancelled out the operation block {  just the while, so that is why there is a fault.

Comment: @XWS: there is a fault in the entire operation either way. Without a try/catch, the exception escapes the entire anonymous method regardless. The question is, why does the fault lead to the task having the `Canceled` state with the `while` and `Faulted` without it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior you're asking about would IMHO be more properly be questioned as "why does the task status transition to `Canceled` when the `while` loop is present?". I say this because the natural reading of the code is that it should *always* transition to `Faulted` instead.

Normally, the way cancellation works is that you only get the `Canceled` state if the `OperationCanceledException` constructor was passed the same `CancellationToken` instance that was passed to the `Task.Run()` method. Otherwise, the task transitions to `Faulted` on any exception.

That this isn't what happens when you add the `while` loop is odd, to say the least. So, why does this odd thing happen?

Well, the answer is found (at least partially) in the code that the compiler generates. Here is the IL for the loop when the `while` loop is present (this IL also includes a diagnostic call to `Console.WriteLine()`, but is otherwise exactly the code you posted):

```
.method public hidebysig instance class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task 
        '<Main>b__1'() cil managed
{
  // Code size       67 (0x43)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init (class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task V_0,
           bool V_1)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  br.s       IL_003f
  IL_0003:  nop
  IL_0004:  ldstr      "sleeping"
  IL_0009:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_000e:  nop
  IL_000f:  ldc.i4     0x12c
  IL_0014:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Threading.Thread::Sleep(int32)
  IL_0019:  nop
  IL_001a:  ldarg.0
  IL_001b:  ldflda     valuetype [mscorlib]System.Threading.CancellationToken TestSO33850046CancelVsFaulted.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass3'::cancellationToken
  IL_0020:  call       instance bool [mscorlib]System.Threading.CancellationToken::get_IsCancellationRequested()
  IL_0025:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0026:  ceq
  IL_0028:  stloc.1
  IL_0029:  ldloc.1
  IL_002a:  brtrue.s   IL_003e
  IL_002c:  nop
  IL_002d:  ldstr      "throwing"
  IL_0032:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0037:  nop
  IL_0038:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.OperationCanceledException::.ctor()
  IL_003d:  throw
  IL_003e:  nop
  IL_003f:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0040:  stloc.1
  IL_0041:  br.s       IL_0003
} // end of method '<>c__DisplayClass3'::'<Main>b__1'
```

Note that even though the method has no `return` statement, the compiler has inferred (for some reason) the method's return type as `Task` instead of `void`. I admit, I have no idea why this should be; the method isn't `async`, never mind does it have any `await`, and the lambda certainly isn't a simple expression evaluating to a `Task` value. But even so, the compiler's decided to implement this method as returning `Task`.

This in turn has an effect on which `Task.Run()` method overload is called. Instead of calling `Task.Run(Action, CancellationToken)`, it will call `Task.Run(Func<Task>, CancellationToken)`. And it turns out that the implementation of each of these two methods is very different from the other. While the `Action` overload simply creates a new `Task` object and starts it, [the `Func<Task>` overload](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,0fb2b4d9262599b9) wraps the created task in an `UnwrapPromise<T>` object, passing to its constructor a flag that tells it to explicitly be on the lookout for `OperationCanceledException` and treat that as a `Canceled` result instead of `Faulted`.

If you comment out the `while`, the compiler implements the anonymous method instead as having a return type of `void`. Likewise if you add a (unreachable) `return` statement after the `while` loop. In either case, this causes the anonymous method to have return type of `void` causing the `Action` overload for `Run()` to be called, which treats `OperationCanceledException` just like any other, transitioning the task into the `Faulted` state instead.

And of course, if you pass the `cancellationToken` value to the `OperationCanceledException` constructor, or call `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` instead of explicitly checking and throwing, the exception itself will correctly indicate that it was thrown according to the `CancellationToken` that was passed to the `Run()` method and thus the task will transition to `Canceled` as would normally be desired in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you for the great research. Although we still have a question "Why the behavior of the compiler so inconsistent?" I am not sure that I'll receive deeper explanations than yours. I'll mark the answer as a right during the day if no other appears.

Comment: Just found quite good explanation on almost the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359761/faulted-vs-canceled-task-status-after-cancellationtoken-throwifcancellationreque

Comment: @Deffiss: yup, that's almost the same question. Only difference is that they aren't passing the token to `Run()` (and so don't expect state `Canceled` even using `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`). As useful is the link to [the answer to the question of why the lambda return type is inferred as it is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24316474/3538012). Short version: the compiler chooses `Func<Task>` over `Action` because it can.

Comment: *They aren't passing the token to `Run`*, AFAIR - the state will still be `Canceled`. Passing it to `Run` is only important when the token is already  canceled, so the task lambda doesn't even run. FYI @Deffiss, too.

Comment: @Noseratio: _"Passing it to Run is only important when the token is already canceled"_ -- nope. try it. If you don't pass the token, and you do use the `Run(Action)` overload, then even if you use `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`, the task completes as `Faulted` instead of `Canceled`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, you're right about the `Task.Run(Action)` override, the token has to be associated with task for proper cancellation propagation. However, it doesn't for the unwrapping `Task.Run(Func<Task>)` override, where the `Func<Task>` doesn't even have to be `async`.

Comment: @Noseratio: _"it doesn't for the unwrapping `Task.Run(Func<Task>)`"_ -- well, sure. That is in fact the entire point of this and the other question. Not sure what clarification you're trying to make here, if any. The difference in the call is related to what the behavior _expected_ by the questioner is, not what the behavior in the case of the `Run(Func<Task>)` overload actually turns out to be.

Comment: You're right, I stand corrected about the `Action`/`Func<SomethingNotTask>` + `token` behavior. I still wanted to point out how `Func<Task>` behavior is different (caused by `Task.Unwrap`).

Comment: @Noseratio: _"I still wanted to point out how Func<Task> behavior is different"_ -- I'm curious: why is that important to point out? Don't the answer above and the one to the very similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359761/faulted-vs-canceled-task-status-after-cancellationtoken-throwifcancellationreque) already adequately point that out?

Comment: Peter, "why is that important to point out?" As a reminder to to myself and others how may bother to read this thread, perhaps. I was the asker/answerer of that very similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359761/faulted-vs-canceled-task-status-after-cancellationtoken-throwifcancellationreque) and now - 1 year later - I forgot that `token` has to be associated with the `Action`-style lambda, as you see.