# Passing cancellation token to Task.Run seems to have no effect

Tags: c#, task, cancellation-token

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-task-and-its-children) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3713113/1836773), passing a cancellation token to a task constructor, or `Task.Run`, will cause the task to be associated with said token, causing the task to transition to `Canceled` instead of `Faulted` if a cancellation exception occurs.

I've been fiddling with these examples for a while, and I can't see any benefits other than preventing a cancelled task to start.

Changing the code on [this MSDN example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-task-and-its-children) from

```
tc = Task.Run(() => DoSomeWork(i, token), token);
```

to

```
tc = Task.Run(() => DoSomeWork(i, token));
```

produced the exact same output:

[image]

This code also results in two cancelled state tasks with the same exceptions thrown:

```
var token = cts.Token;

var t1 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    };
});

var t2 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    };
}, token);

Console.ReadKey();

try
{
    cts.Cancel();
    Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    if (e is AggregateException)
    {
        foreach (var ex in (e as AggregateException).InnerExceptions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            
}

Console.WriteLine($"without token: { t1.Status }");
Console.WriteLine($"with token: { t2.Status }");
Console.WriteLine("Done.");
```

[image]

Apparently, throwing `OperationCanceledException` from within the task is enough to make it transition to `Canceled` instead of `Faulted`. So my question is: is there a reason for passing the token to the task other than preventing a cancelled task to run?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should see the difference when you start with a cancelled token.

Comment: It has, and if you read my question you will notice that I linked the most relevant.

Comment: "preventing a cancelled task to start" is exactly the point I think, I don;t see why you need another reason

Comment: Because every answer related to this question states that there are 2 reasons, the other one being preventing the task from going to faulted state, but doesn't seem to be working that way anymore.

Comment: Works fine for me: shows `Canceled` with a token and `Faulted` without, this is on .NET 6 https://dotnetfiddle.net/ldtqW5

Comment: The answer that you've linked is actually a perfect duplicate and I'm closing the question as such. If you use anything _other_ than cooperative cancellation (aka, `throw new Exception()` instead of `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();`, you WILL see the task transition to `Faulted`, (as Charlie was kind enough to demonstrate) in your first case, whereas the second will always transition to `Canceled`.

Comment: @DavidL AFAICS the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712939/cancellation-token-in-task-constructor-why/3713113#3713113) doesn't explain why the `t1`, which is not passed a `cancellationToken`, ends up in a `Canceled` state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a reason for passing the token to the task other than preventing a cancelled task to run?

In this particular case, No. Past the point in time that the task has started running, the `token` has no effect to the outcome.

The `Task.Run` method has many overloads. This case is peculiar because of the infinite `while` loop.

```
var t1 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    };
});
```

The compiler has to choose between these two overloads:

```
public static Task Run(Action action);

public static Task Run(Func<Task> function);
```

...and for a reason explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316189/peculiar-overload-resolution-with-while-true) it chooses the later. [Here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/ed2a5a1492edda956323086e6cb1a456d9418f44/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L5444) is the implementation of this overload:

```
public static Task Run(Func<Task?> function, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (function == null) ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.function);

    // Short-circuit if we are given a pre-canceled token
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        return Task.FromCanceled(cancellationToken);

    // Kick off initial Task, which will call the user-supplied function and yield a Task.
    Task<Task?> task1 = Task<Task?>.Factory.StartNew(function, cancellationToken,
        TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);

    // Create a promise-style Task to be used as a proxy for the operation
    // Set lookForOce == true so that unwrap logic can be on the lookout for OCEs thrown
    // as faults from task1, to support in-delegate cancellation.
    UnwrapPromise<VoidTaskResult> promise = new UnwrapPromise<VoidTaskResult>(task1,
        lookForOce: true);

    return promise;
}
```

The important detail is the `lookForOce: true`. Let's look [inside](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/ed2a5a1492edda956323086e6cb1a456d9418f44/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L6813) the `UnwrapPromise` class:

```
// "Should we check for OperationCanceledExceptions on the outer task and interpret them
// as proxy cancellation?"
// Unwrap() sets this to false, Run() sets it to true.
private readonly bool _lookForOce;
```

..and at [another point](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/ed2a5a1492edda956323086e6cb1a456d9418f44/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L6941) below:

```
case TaskStatus.Faulted:
    List<ExceptionDispatchInfo> edis = task.GetExceptionDispatchInfos();
    ExceptionDispatchInfo oceEdi;
    if (lookForOce && edis.Count > 0 &&
        (oceEdi = edis[0]) != null &&
        oceEdi.SourceException is OperationCanceledException oce)
    {
        result = TrySetCanceled(oce.CancellationToken, oceEdi);
    }
    else
    {
        result = TrySetException(edis);
    }
    break;
```

So although the internally created `Task<Task?> task1` ends up in a `Faulted` state, its unwrapped version ends up as `Canceled`, because the type of the exception is
`OperationCanceledException` (abbreviated as `oce` in the code).

That's a quite convoluted journey in the history of TPL, with methods introduced at different times and frameworks, in order to serve different purposes. The end result is a little bit of inconsistency, or nuanced behavior if you prefer to say it so. A relevant article that you might find interesting is this: [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/) by Stephen Toub.

Comment: Ohh I see... I had not caught that detail about the chosen overload, I dug straight into the Run(Action action) one. When forcing the code to actually use that, the final state is indeed Faulted. And so you have found the culprit. This is actually new information, including all the similar questions asked here before. Thanks.