# Faulted vs Canceled task status after CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token

Usually I don't post a question with the answer, but this time I'd like to attract some attention to what I think might be an obscure yet common issue. It was triggered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24346706/1768303), since then I reviewed my own old code and found some of it was affected by this, too.

The code below starts and awaits two tasks, `task1` and `task2`, which are almost identical. `task1` is only different from `task2` in that it runs a never-ending loop. IMO, both cases are quite typical for some real-life scenarios performing CPU-bound work.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        static async Task TestAsync()
        {
            var ct = new CancellationTokenSource(millisecondsDelay: 1000);
            var token = ct.Token;

            // start task1
            var task1 = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (var i = 0; ; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(i); // simulate work item #i
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }
            });

            // start task2
            var task2 = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(i); // simulate work item #i
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }
            });  

            // await task1
            try
            {
                await task1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(new { task = "task1", ex.Message, task1.Status });
            }

            // await task2
            try
            {
                await task2;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(new { task = "task2", ex.Message, task2.Status });
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestAsync().Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The fiddle [is here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mMErYR). The output:

```
{ task = task1, Message = The operation was canceled., Status = Canceled }
{ task = task2, Message = The operation was canceled., Status = Faulted }
```

**Why the status of `task1` is `Cancelled`, but the status of `task2` is `Faulted`?** Note, in both cases I do *not* pass `token` as the 2nd parameter to `Task.Run`.

Comment: I'm glad my posts provoked your questions.

Comment: @l3arnon, it was a great post, indeed, both of them, in fact.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two problems here. First, it's always a good idea to pass `CancellationToken` to the `Task.Run` API, besides making it available to the task's lambda. Doing so associates the token with the task and is vital for the correct propagation of the cancellation triggered by `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`.

This however doesn't explain why the cancellation status for `task1` still gets propagated correctly (`task1.Status == TaskStatus.Canceled`), while it doesn't for `task2` (`task2.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted`).

Now, this might be one of those very rare cases where the clever C# type inference logic can play against the developer's will. It's discussed in great details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11941779/1768303) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24316189/1768303). To sum up, in case with `task1`, the following override of `Task.Run` is inferred by compiler:

```
public static Task Run(Func<Task> function)
```

rather than:

```
public static Task Run(Action action)
```

That's because the `task1` lambda has no natural code path out of the `for` loop, so it may as well be a `Func<Task>` lambda, **despite it is not `async` and it doesn't return anything**. This is the option that compiler favors more than `Action`. Then, the use of such override of `Task.Run` is equivalent to this:

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(new Func<Task>(() =>
{
    for (var i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(i); // simulate work item #i
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
})).Unwrap();
```

A nested task of type `Task<Task>` is returned by `Task.Factory.StartNew`, which gets [unwrapped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795275%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `Task` by `Unwrap()`. `Task.Run` [is smart enough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) to do such unwrapping automatically for when it accepts `Func<Task>`. **The unwrapped promise-style task correctly propagates the cancellation status from its inner task**, thrown as an `OperationCanceledException` exception by the `Func<Task>` lambda. This doesn't happen for `task2`, which accepts an `Action` lambda and doesn't create any inner tasks. The cancellation doesn't get propagated for `task2`, because `token` has not been associated with `task2` via `Task.Run`.

In the end, this may be a desired behavior for `task1` (certainly not for `task2`), but we don't want to create nested tasks behind the scene in either case. Moreover, this behavior for `task1` may easily get broken by introducing a conditional `break` out of the `for` loop.

**The correct code for `task1` should be this**:

```
var task1 = Task.Run(new Action(() =>
{
    for (var i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(i); // simulate work item #i
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}), token);
```

Comment: So when a token is implicitly passed `Task.Run` instead of explicitly via a parameter, it is considered as every other exception that happened inside the lambda? I tried browsing through the CancellationToken registration but couldn't figure much out of it in the source

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, that's true for `Task.Run`. However, for a plain `async Task` method the magic is done by the `async/await` compiler infrastructure code: `async Task TestAsync(CancellationToken token) { token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); }` would return a `Task` with `task.IsCanceled == true`, if cancellation was requested on the token.

Comment: That's interesting. I wonder why they behave differently. Would an async lambda behave like `task1` or `task2`? or will it differ depending on the return delegate type?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, me too. `Task.Run`, `Task.Factory.StartNew()`, `new Task()` and `Task.ContinueWith` give us an option to explicitly associate the token with the task they create. OTOH, an `async Task` method doesn't have that option, another C# syntax extension would be required for that. I guess, this might be the reason.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, an `async` lambda would behave like `task1`, as it would create a nested task which `Task.Run` would unwrap. This however would be an expected behavior we could rely on. The trick with the `task1` from above is that the lambda is not `async`, but is still treated as `Func<Task>`.

Comment: It seems like they are taking token by ref instead of by value. Throwing twice might be the problem

Comment: @zahir, not sure what you mean. A token, although of a value type, itself holds a reference to its parent `CancellationTokenSource` (same as `CancellationTokenRegistration` does). You can have multiple tokens referring to the same source, and cancellation is requested via the source, not via the token.

Comment: @Noseratio I can't truely understand the compilers behavior regarding lambda overload resolution, as per the previous question by l3arnon. Cant really get my head around why the compiler is infering a `Func<Task>` from infinite loops.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11941779/1768303) for hopefully a better explanation of it.

Comment: @Noseratio I did read them both. What i dont understand is why a lambda with a return type other than `void` is considered a better resolution than a non `void` lambda.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I see. That's because `Task SomeMethod() { throw new Exception(); }` is a legal, compile-able method in C#. It doesn't return anything yet it can be cast to `Func<Task>`, and so can the lambda from `task1`. This lambda can also be cast to `Action`, but following up on @svick's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11941780/1768303) (the part in bold), the C# language specs dictate that `Func<Task>` is a more favorable choice, and so it goes with `task1`.

Comment: Right. I'll think ill have to accept that fact until i can understand why MSFT made the choice of the "better overload" being the `Func<Task>`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I tend to agree, I'd also prefer to not have such implicit ambiguity in C#. Alternatively, the TPL designers might consider offering something like `Task.RunAsync(Func<Task> func, ...)` to kill a possibility for this ambiguity, rather than having those two overrides for `Task.Run()`.

Comment: @Noseratio I mailed Eric Lippert and asked him to comment on the lambda inference. He answered: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24316474/1870803