# Task.Run and CancellationToken. How does cancellation work in this scenario?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

Why do we have 2 different results in next 2 scenarios? In these samples
token.IsCancellationRequested = true. Why does functionality have changed if i comment if(token.IsCancellationRequested), when in fact we can type if(true) instead of it.

Somewhere i read that in order to have TaskCanceledException ( Status = Canceled ) we need to follow next 3 conditions:

1. Throw OperationCanceledException and pass token to it's constructor
2. Pass the same token to the method, which creates a task (Task.Run)
3. IsCancellationRequested should be true.

And it's true, if we use if(token.IsCancellationRequested) throw new OperationCanceledException(token) (equals to token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested) (second scenario) , we need to follow 2 other contidionts, but in first scenario if we comment if(token.IsCancellationRequested) (we can even remove 1 from CTS constructor ) we will still get Canceled status.

**1. Here Status is Canceled**

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(1);
        var token = cts.Token;
        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
                Thread.Sleep(5);
                // if(token.IsCancellationRequested)
                throw new OperationCanceledException(token);
        });

        Thread.Sleep(50);
        Console.WriteLine(task.Status);
```

**2. Here - Faulted.**

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(1);
        var token = cts.Token;
        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5); 
            if(token.IsCancellationRequested) // true
                throw new OperationCanceledException(token);
        });

        Thread.Sleep(50);
        Console.WriteLine(task.Status);
```

Comment: BTW - Rather than test/throw yourself you should just be calling `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`

Comment: if(token.IsCancellationRequested)  throw new OperationCanceledException(token) is equal to ThrowIfCancellationRequested, but somewhere i read that in order to have TaskCanceledException ( Status = Canceled ) we need to:
1. Throw OperationCanceledException and pass token to it's constructor
2. Pass the same token to the method, which creates a task (Task.Run)
3. IsCancellationRequested should be true

Comment: I think `TaskCanceledException` is just the result of catching a `OperationCanceledException`. But the canonical way of doing this is to use `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` which depends on `IsCancellationRequested`

Comment: Your two examples call different overloads of `Task.Run()`, which in turn have different behaviors with respect to cancellation. See duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that if the compiler can know at compile time that the task will always throw `OperationCanceledException` is will end in `Canceled` state, otherwize it will end in `Faulted`.

```
void Main()
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(1);
    cts.Cancel();
    var token = cts.Token;
    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //if(GetTrue())  //Faulted
        if(true)         //Canceled
            throw new OperationCanceledException();
    });
    
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    Console.WriteLine(task.Status);
}

bool GetTrue()
{
    return true;
}
```

But if you send in the same token to the `Task.Run` as you throw inside the task it will end in `Canceled`.

```
void Main()
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(10000);
    var token = cts.Token;
    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }, token);
    
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    Console.WriteLine(task.Status);
}
```

Comment: The underlying reason that the compiler "seems" to "know" is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359761/faulted-vs-canceled-task-status-after-cancellationtoken-throwifcancellationreque