# How to fix the inconsistent cancellation behavior of Task.Run?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, task-parallel-library, cancellation

The [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method has overloads that accept both sync and async delegates:

```
public static Task Run (Action action);
public static Task Run (Func<Task> function);
```

Unfortunately these overloads don't behave the same when the delegate throws an `OperationCanceledException`. The sync delegate results in a `Faulted` task, and the async delegate results in a `Canceled` task. Here is a minimal demonstration of this behavior:

```
CancellationToken token = new(canceled: true);

Task taskSync = Task.Run(() => token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested());
Task taskAsync = Task.Run(async () => token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested());
    
try { Task.WaitAll(taskSync, taskAsync); } catch { }
    
Console.WriteLine($"taskSync.Status: {taskSync.Status}"); // Faulted
Console.WriteLine($"taskAsync.Status: {taskAsync.Status}"); // Canceled (undesirable)
```

Output:

```
taskSync.Status: Faulted
taskAsync.Status: Canceled
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/otT0Pq).

This inconsistency has been observed also in this question:

- [Faulted vs Canceled task status after CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359761/faulted-vs-canceled-task-status-after-cancellationtoken-throwifcancellationreque)

That question asks about the "why". My question here is how to fix it. Specifically **my question is:** How to implement a variant of the `Task.Run` with async delegate, that behaves like the built-in `Task.Run` with sync delegate? In case of an `OperationCanceledException` it should complete asynchronously as `Faulted`, except when the supplied `cancellationToken` argument matches the [token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.operationcanceledexception.cancellationtoken) stored in the exception, in which case it should complete as `Canceled`.

```
public static Task TaskRun2 (Func<Task> action,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
```

Here is some code with the desirable behavior of the requested method:

```
CancellationToken token = new(canceled: true);

Task taskA = TaskRun2(async () => token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested());
Task taskB = TaskRun2(async () => token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(), token);
    
try { Task.WaitAll(taskA, taskB); } catch { }
    
Console.WriteLine($"taskA.Status: {taskA.Status}");
Console.WriteLine($"taskB.Status: {taskB.Status}");
```

Desirable output:

```
taskA.Status: Faulted
taskB.Status: Canceled
```

Comment: That seems hard to do without reimplementing unwrapping task from `Task<Task>`. Even `StartNew` which is used by `Task.Run` will ignore the token if you pass it `Func<Task`, any async code will do the same.

Comment: @Evk you are right about the `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Actually I have come up with a solution, a quite compact one, that I intend to post as a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) tomorrow if the question is still unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is to use the existing `Task.Run` method, and attach a [`ContinueWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith) continuation that alters its cancellation behavior. The continuation returns either the original task or a faulted task, so it returns a `Task<Task>`. Eventually this nested task is unwrapped to a simple `Task`, with the help of the [`Unwrap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap) method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Queues the specified work to run on the thread pool, and returns a proxy
/// for the task returned by the action. The cancellation behavior is the same
/// with the Task.Run(Action, CancellationToken) method.
/// </summary>
public static Task TaskRun2 (Func<Task> action,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(action);
    return Task.Run(action, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsCanceled)
        {
            CancellationToken taskToken = new TaskCanceledException(t).CancellationToken;
            if (taskToken != cancellationToken)
                return Task.FromException(new OperationCanceledException(taskToken));
        }
        return t;
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach |
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
        TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
}
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pi0FcI).

The [`TaskCanceledException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcanceledexception.-ctor) constructor is used in order to get access to the `CancellationToken` stored inside the canceled `Task`. Unfortunately the `Task.CancellationToken` property [is not exposed](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/62006) (it is `internal`), but fortunately this workaround exists.